# Got an error in jsp page in html tag ? how to find out?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Multiple annotations found at this line:

- No end tag ().
- Starttag() no closed.

```
<td class="form_label" align="right">
    pH VALUE IN THE&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    SOIL&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
<td align="left" colspan="2">
    <html:select
     property="choosePhVal" styleId="choosePhVal" style="width:150px">
        <html:option value="-">[-- Select --]</html:option>
        <html:option value="<6.5"><6.5</html:option>
        <html:option value="6.5-7.5">6.5-7.5</html:option>
        <html:option value=">7.5">>7.5</html:option>
    </html:select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's your problem:

```
<html:option value="<6.5"><6.5</html:option>
<html:option value="6.5-7.5">6.5-7.5</html:option>
<html:option value=">7.5">>7.5</html:option>
```

Replace those lines with:

```
<html:option value="&lt;6.5">&lt;6.5</html:option>
<html:option value="6.5-7.5">6.5-7.5</html:option>
<html:option value="&gt;7.5">&gt;7.5</html:option>
```

The `<` and `>` tags in your values were being interpreted as HTML start & end tags. I replaced them with their HTML entity equivalents.